# AngularJS - Using ng-repeat twice under the same controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following DIV:

```
<div ng-controller="userControl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <u>{{user.id}} : {{user.name}}</u><br />
        <div ng-repeat="role in user.roles">
            {{role.name}}
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <form ng-submit="addRoleToUser()">
        <select name="userSelect">
        <div ng-repeat="user in users">
                <option value="{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</option>
        </div>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
function userControl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.users = [
                        {"id":"0","name":"Username1","roles":[{}]},
                        {"id":"1","name":"Username2","roles":[{}]},
                    ]

    $scope.addUser = function() {
        var nextid = $scope.getNextId();
        $scope.users.push({id:nextid,name:$scope.userName});
        /*
        $.post({}); //Push changes to server
        */
        $scope.userName = '';
    };

    $scope.getNextId = function() {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function(data) {
          count = data.id;
        });
        var count2 = parseInt(count)+1;
        return count2;
     };

}
```

I can see the first ng-repeat is working fine and is listing the `user.id` and `user.name`, however the second ng-repeat (the one inside the form) does not display the information, is that related to the fact that I've already looped through that element in the previous div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misused the select directive :

```
<select ng-model="selectedUser" name="userSelect" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users">
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: This is working great, can you maybe explain why my way didn't work? (I realize it's not the best way of doing it, but I was under the impression it should work)